How to make an html popup that take variable input
I have instructions with pictures that get displayed when a user clicks a link.
I know how to create a "static" popup - one that has a static image. I'd like to create a single parameterized popup that would display the image I tell it to.
I want to do something like this :
I am writing some instructions about how to use the <a href="javascript:alert('dishwasher.jpg');">dishwasher </a>
and the <a href="javascript:alert('washing machine.jpg');">washing machine</a>, etc.
<script>
function alert(image) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
<!--   somehow tell the popup to show image -->
  popup.classList.toggle("show");

}</script>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
</div> 

This is based on https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

Do yourself a favor and stay as far away from W3Schools as you can. They are well-known to provide incomplete, inaccurate, and out of date information. Even the code you are trying that is based on their example uses  20 year old legacy techniques to accomplish the task. Instead, use a trusted authority like the Mozilla Developer Network - https://developer.mozilla.org/

You can use the new <dialog> element and showModal() functionality:


I am writing some instructions about how to use the
<button onclick="showPopup('dishwasher')">dishwasher</button> and the
<button onclick="showPopup('washingmachine')">washing machine</button> , etc.

<script>
  function showPopup(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).showModal()
  }
</script>

<dialog id="dishwasher">
  Dish Washer
</dialog>
<dialog id="washingmachine">
  Washing Machine
</dialog>



Note that ESC closes the modal. You may want to implement close() into a link inside the modal as a more intuitive control
For parameterized image you could do something like this:


I am writing some instructions about how to use the
<button onclick="showPopupImage('dishwasher', 'dishwasher.jpg')">dishwasher</button> and the
<button onclick="showPopupImage('washingmachine', 'washingmachine.jpg')">washing machine</button> , etc.

<script>
  function showPopupImage(alt, src) {
    const popup = document.getElementById('image-popup')
    popup.querySelector('img').src = src
    popup.querySelector('img').alt = alt
    popup.showModal()
  }
</script>

<dialog id="image-popup">
  <img src="#" alt="" />
</dialog>




You really shouldn't use <a> elements as JavaScript "hooks". Any visible element supports a click event. <a> elements are semantically for navigation and using them otherwise creates accessibility concerns.

Thanks very much Zach. That is exactly what I wanted.

@ScottMarcus Was keeping it inline with the question but yes buttons are be better
